# How to force the return type of a match to ()?

Tags: rust

In the following simplified example, the compiler complains that one branch of the `match` statement returns `bool`, while the other returns `()`.

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        match available.get(&i) {
            Some(s) => set.insert(*s),
            None => ()
        }
    }
}
```

This results in an error however:

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
8  | /         match available.get(&i) {
9  | |             Some(s) => set.insert(*s),
   | |                        -------------- this is found to be of type `bool`
10 | |             None => ()
   | |                     ^^ expected `bool`, found `()`
11 | |         }
   | |_________- `match` arms have incompatible types
```

How can I inform the compiler that the match statement should return `()`, and that the `bool` returned from `insert` should be ignored?

Comment: You can use `_ = set.insert(*s)` to turn the method call expression into an assignment statement. Alternatively, wrap it in a block and put a `;` after the method call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual way would just be to put the arm in a block and cap it with a `;`, as that suppresses the result of the expression:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        match available.get(&i) {
            Some(s) => {
                set.insert(*s);
            }
            None => (),
        }
    }
}
```

A probably less common alternative would be to feed the value to a function "converting" it to a `()` e.g. [`drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html)

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        match available.get(&i) {
            Some(s) => drop(set.insert(*s)),
            None => (),
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just ignore the second branch entirely:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        if let Some(s) = available.get(&i) {
            set.insert(*s);
        }
    }
}
```

or use a higher-order function for this side effect, which while not the most common is a thing:

```rust
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        available.get(&i).map(|&s| set.insert(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: With only 2 variants total `if let` is probably the cleanest way to write this.

Answer (score 5):

You could turn both blocks into statements:

```rust
match available.get(&i) {
    Some(s) => {
        set.insert(*s);
    }
    None => {}
}
```

Or you could convert the `match` to an `if`-`let`:

```rust
if let Some(&s) = available.get(&i) {
    set.insert(s);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of turning `()` into `{}` in the `None` branch? It doesn't change anything.

Comment: For parallelism. What's the point of writing it as `()`?

Comment: It's just a very minor nitpick, but I would stick to the style used in the question so it's clear that what you changed is required to solve the issue, especially if it's not a change  that `rustfmt` would enforce. For instance, nobody replaced `for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` by `for i in 1..=5`, despite the latter being the more idiomatic style.

Comment: I appreciate the perspective. I like code snippets in my answers to reflect good style throughout because readers are often skimming them and might copy and paste the code, warts and all. Best to have no warts.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is exploiting that `Option` is iterable and `&str` is `Copy`, so you can pass the option returned by `available.get()` to [`Extend::extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.extend-1):

```
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

fn main() {
    let available = HashMap::<i32, &str>::from_iter([(2, "b"), (3, "c"), (4, "d")]);
    let mut set = HashSet::<&str>::new();
    
    for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {
        set.extend(available.get(&i));
    }
}
```

Note that this requires additional type annotations in this particular case.

The for loop can be rewritten in functional style as

```
set.extend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().map(|i| available.get(i)).flatten());
```